# A more basic question, but why is my variable in python not being properly defined?

Tags: python

I'm currently a student working on a simple piece of code to find my way around python. I don't know why my variable numOp, shown below, isn't being set to i. When I put in an answer that it has in operations, like "what can you do", it is supposed to set numOp to the index of that question in operations. Just to be clear, the variable answer is the result of an input and will contain a question in operations.

[image]

Comment: add code as code block

Comment: You should use `for i in range(0, lenOp):` you forgot the `range` function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please dont post code as a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

`(0, lenOp)` is being considered a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) the way you've used it. If you want a range of integers from 0 to lenOp, you want to use `range(0, lenOp)` or, simply, `range(lenOp)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
operations = ["what is my name", "what can you do", "set a timer"]

numOP: int

if answer in operations:
  for idx, op in enumerate(operations):
    if op == answer:
    numOp = idx
    break
  print(numOp)
```

enumerate gives you the index + the value of the current rotation through your list.